# How to generate new Topic for new documents?

Tags: clustering, topic-models

what approach would help me generate new topics for new documents?
I read [this page](http://akuz.me/2014/01/lda-topic-keywords/) in order to learn more about the effect of specifying keywords for the topics that we care about detecting in new documents, but the problem of generating new topics having a given set of topics is still unresolved.

Comment: Have a look at [document classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_classification).

Comment: From my present topics that generated with LDA(in R),i wish to generate automaticlly new topic for new documents

Comment: @Vampir, the link you provide is returning a 404. Perhaps you could update that?

Answer (score 1):

An idea is to perform some standard clustering algorithm to group similar documents together. Then on each cluster you perform a data mining approach, e.g. Apriori, to find itemsets of two-grams or three-grams that appear significantly often in the cluster. You can use those sets of words as new 'topics'.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse.Should i perform a data mining approach over my LDA result ?

Answer (score 1):

Your link unfortunately doesn't work but, have you tried basic [Latent Dirichlet Allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation)? This generates topics for you, along with the words and frequencies that define those topics. These models can be fed in an initial list of topics, and by adding documents you can set a penalty for whether or not to introduce new topics.

In general, clustering topics is a difficult task (PCA generally only explains a few percent of the total variance). I would strongly recommend trying something like [LDAvis](https://pyldavis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html).

Otherwise, if you're interested in richer document details, you'd wanna try [word2vec models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec), which you can try to cluster after forming vectors for your documents.